# MySQL : not able to delete multiple records in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning `SQL` and I try some things in `phpMyAdmin` like creating or deleting tables, creating or deleting records and so on...
Let's assume I have a table where there are 2 columns - `id` and `name` populated with 7 records. Now I want to delete some records whose id is 5 and 6. 
My query is like this:

`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 5 AND id = 6`

This query isn't working. But if I'll write `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 5` without AND condition, it will work. Am I do something wrong?

Comment: Hint:  `OR`.  Or `IN`.

Comment: A row can't have an id equal to 5 _and_ 6 at the same time

Comment: `Where id in (5,6)`. `And` means both conditions should match which is impossible..U need to use `OR` or `In(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the *logic* of what you are saying. That query says that the row must have an `id` that simultaneously equals 5 and 6, which we know is impossible.

You could have `column1 = stack` and `column2 = overflow`, because those are two columns and thus could have different values, but the ***same*** column cannot contain multiple values in a single row.

So instead, try using the `OR` operator. Which has logic like: *Delete the row from the table where the ID equals this or the row in the table equals that*

Like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 5 OR id = 6
```

Comment: Understand) So how can I delete 2 records using only one query? I thought if I'll say id=5 and id=6 it will delete record 5 and 6))

Comment: Try using the query I posted above. By switching the `AND` to `OR`, the database will understand to delete all records where `id=5` OR where `id=6`. Though in English we may be able to say "Delete them if they are 5 and 6", the proper grammar (and thus, understood by the database) would be "Delete them if they are 5 or 6". Computers are not quite as smart as us :)

Comment: Understand) Thanks, I'll accept your answer :) Good luck)

Comment: But after 7 minutes))

Comment: No problem. Please comment if there is a question or you need more clarification.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using AND in condition then mysql will match or satisfy both conditions which is impossible for single row in your case to match it so instead you should try:

DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 5 OR id = 6;

OR

DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id IN (5,6);

You can try any of the above two query.

Comment: It is impossible for the first statement in your `OR` clause to work properly.

Comment: Yes Jerry that was a typing mistake, typed AND instead of OR